# Allow to submit an answer with Ctrl + Enter

Tags: feature-request, answers, keyboard-shortcuts, form-submit

As far as I can tell, whenever I try to submit an answer with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>, it doesn't work. As this is allowed on edits, reviews, and question asks I would be very happy to see this on answers too.

Comment: Is that supposed to work? I don't think I've ever heard of that

Comment: @MichaelMrozek Works with edit, ask (iirc) + review.

Comment: Definitely not [tag:bug]...

Comment: @Mooseman Huh? This works on (most) other SO forms...

Comment: Perhaps it's a bit of a nudge to users that they ought to think a little more about their answers before summarily posting them with a hot-key to save 500 milliseconds.

Comment: It indeed works on questions/edit. Reproduced on the [sandbox](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox).

Comment: @RobertHarvey Why is it allowed on questions then??

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance I believe this is either [feature-request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request) or [status-bydesign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

Comment: i dont see why is that important you can always use the button [ Post Your Answer ] .. not that hard to move the mouse and click it :D

Comment: It isn't: it's just a small convenience that I would appreciate.

Answer (score 12):

We already have keyboard shortcuts for most actions on post, voting, flagging/moderating, editing, etc. and the shortcut is already enabled for post edition. Seems easy to just allow post submission, no?

Also, it's annoying to reach for the mouse just to submit your answer :(

Answer (score 6):

<kbd>tab</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> already works; why have another shortcut for it?

Comment: This is First Tab Then Enter, not "Hold Tab and Hit Enter"

Answer (score 1):

If you can see this, I successfully submitted this answer by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>, thanks to the [SE like I like it](https://stackapps.com/q/5038/34737) user script. I got a “Do you want to leave this page?”, but apart from that it worked fine.

Comment: You sure?  I've tried Ctrl+Enter and Shift+Enter at the sandbox, nuthin'.

Comment: Yes, I tested it with this very answer and have been using it like since I can think. Could be browser- and settings-specific though.

Comment: @Ollie Same. I can't get it to work at the sandbox. Not in Mardown mode, not in RT mode, and not even using the old editor.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft What browser are you using? I tested it on Chrome on Windows.

Comment: @41686d6564: Firefox on Linux (with Tridactyl, but that doesn’t seem to occupy that shortcut).

Comment: @Wrzlprmft I can't get it to work even in Firefox.

Comment: @Ollie: I found the culprit. See my edit.