# On "Ask a question", Ctrl+Enter in the Tags text input field should submit the question

Tags: feature-request, keyboard, form-submit

When composing or editing a question, and you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> while the cursor is in the question body, it submits the question. That's great. Now why not make <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> submit this question regardless of whether the cursor is in the question body or the Title or the Tags fields?

Comment: Same request regarding posting answers: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/189203/246931

Answer (score 5):

In the tag editor or title editor you can just hit <kbd>enter</kbd> to submit your question (without any <kbd>ctrl</kbd>s).

Comment: True, no need for any special behaviour. And I'd really prefer to get to know my browser (where indeed most browsers, if not all, submit a form when hitting Return in form inputs that are not text areas), rather than relying on specific behaviour on specific websites, and then be confused on other websites that use different hacks.

Comment: Why do I need to remember different controls for different inputs when we can have one control, ctrl-enter, to work everywhere?